# return on ajax jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to return true or false  depending of the result of an ajax jquery call,how I can make it  an asynchronous call ,this I get a Promise object in pending state

```
   function codeExists(code){
    return Promise.resolve($.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "ajax.php",
      data: { op:'codeExists', code: code }
    })
      .done(function( response ) {
        if(response == '1')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
      }));
}
```

Comment: are you trying to see if the call was successful or not?

Comment: @FabioEnne ,changed

Comment: Remove the `Promise.resolve` wrapper, `$.ajax` returns a promise for you.   The return in the `done` does nothing as it only returns a value from that function (the done function) and you can't call that code directly.  It's nonsensical to have a return there.